# Only include grouped observations where event order is valid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of dates for eye exams and eye wear purchases for individuals. I only want to keep instances where individuals bought their eye wear following an eye exam. In the example below, I would want to keep person 1, events 2 and 3 for person 2, person 3, but not person 4. How can I do this in SQL server?

```
| Person | Event  | Order |
|    1   |  Exam  |    1  |
|    1   | Eyewear|    2  | 
|    2   | Eyewear|    1  |
|    2   | Exam   |    2  | 
|    2   | Eyewear|    3  |
|    3   | Exam   |    1  | 
|    3   | Eyewear|    2  |
|    4   | Eyewear|    1  | 
|    4   | Exam   |    2  |
```

The final result would look like

```
| Person | Event  | Order |
|    1   |  Exam  |    1  |
|    1   | Eyewear|    2  | 
|    2   | Exam   |    2  | 
|    2   | Eyewear|    3  |
|    3   | Exam   |    1  | 
|    3   | Eyewear|    2  |
```

Comment: Expected results please.

Comment: @Sami Oops, added!

Comment: is it *immediately* followed by the exam or can it be at any later date?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala As long as the eyeglasses came after an exam, I do not care about the date.

Answer (score 1):

Self join should work...

```
select
    t.Person
    ,t.Event
    ,t.[Order]
from
    yourTable t
    inner join
    yourTable t2 on t2.Person = t.Person
    and t2.[Order] = (t.[Order] +1)
where
    t2.Event = 'Eyewear'
    and t.Event = 'Exam'
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I just changed  the condition on the join to be t2.[Order] > t.[Order] to include situations where they may have gotten more than one pair of glasses after an eye exam.

Comment: Aaaa, I don't know whats happening but for some reason the code will only return exams.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to optimize it but this seems to work:

```
create table t(
  person varchar(10),
  event varchar(10),
  [order] varchar(10)
);
insert into t values
('1','Exam','1'),
('1','Eyewear','2'),
('2','Eyewear','1'),
('2','Exam','2'),
('2','Eyewear','3'),
('3','Exam','1'),
('3','Eyewear','2'),
('4','Eyewear','1'),
('4','Exam','2');

with xxx(person,event_a,seq_a,event_b,seq_b) as (
  select a.person,a.event,a.[order],b.event,b.[order]
    from t a join t b
      on a.person = b.person
      and a.[order] < b.[order]
      and a.event like 'exam'
      and b.event like 'eyewear'
  )
select person,event_a event,seq_a [order] from xxx
union
select person,event_b event,seq_b [order] from xxx
  order by 1,3
```